# Is NVIDIA GeForce 840M suitable for overclocking?

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

I'd like to squeeze a little more performance by overclocking it but I'm afraid it might damage the card if I overclocked it too much.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. It's suitable for overclocking. [**This officially supports Overclocking**](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-840m/features)
[**GPU Boost 2.0**](http://www.geforce.com//hardware/technology/gpu-boost-2/technology) is a featured overclocking technology dedicated for [**GeForce-840M**](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-840m)
Using this overclocking feature is safe. Though use it with care.

EDIT:

GPU Boost 2.0 is a hardware-based technology and exists in GeForce 840M.
You can install [Nvidia nTune](http://www.nvidia.com/object/ntune_2.00.23.html), this adds "Performance" section to the main "Nvidia Control Panel".
You can take control of overclocking  by free apps:
1. [NVIDIA SYSTEM TOOLS](http://www.nvidia.com/object/nvidia-system-tools-6.08-driver.html) -- [Download link](http://www.nvidia.com/object/nvidia-system-tools-6.08-driver.html)
2. [NvGpuPro](http://www.nvgpupro.com/) -- [Download link](http://www.nvgpupro.com/download.php)
3. [MSI Afterburner](http://event.msi.com/vga/afterburner/overview.htm) -- [Download link](http://event.msi.com/vga/afterburner/download.htm)
4. [EVGA PRECISION X](http://www.evga.com/precision/#Overview) -- [Download link](http://www.techspot.com/downloads/5348-evga-precision-x.html)

Use 1 and 2 simultaneously, but if you use 3rd then don't use 4th one, and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't seem to understand how GPU Boost 2.0 works, does it need to be downloaded? Otherwise how do you use it?

Comment: @MegaRodeon I updated my answer with download links. GPU Boost 2.0 is a hardware-based technology and exists in GeForce 840M..

Comment: Thank  you for the update. I've used EVGA Precision X before and I heard it doesn't support mobile GPUs. Now I have the NVIDIA System Tools and NvGpuPro installed, and trying to see if there are performance differences.